# Passing data between viewcontrollers with const unsigned char

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass a const unsigned char variable to another view controller.

```
ServerViewController *viewController = [[ServerViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.socketResponse = response;
```

When I check socketResponse on the viewcontroller it's null(debug), but the response variable is not null, and is the data I want sent over.

```
@property (nonatomic) const unsigned char *socketResponse;
```

Comment: To debug override the setter method

-(void)setSocketResponse:(unsigned char *)response 
{
    socketResponse = response;
}

may be you will get to know exact reason

Comment: Are you sure response is not null when assigning ?

Comment: Response inside the view controller i am sending from has the right value. But it can't send it for some reason.

Comment: If I try to pass a string, it won't work either.

Comment: Fixed it! I changed the way I set it.